# convert/port vertex shader calcuation to java

Tags: java, opengl-es, vector, matrix, shader

I want to animate meshes via bones. However, since my android galaxy s2 supports only 304 vertex shader variables, I think I need to compute the missing bone transformation matrices and the new vertex positions already in Java.

Anyway, how can I convert it to be equivalent? (I actually just want to exclude this as a error source)

```c
uniform mat4  u_BoneTransform[128];
in  vec3  in_Position;
in  vec4  in_BoneID;
in  vec4  in_Weights;

vec3 position = (in_Weights[0] * (u_BoneTransform[ int(in_BoneID[0]) ] * vec4(in_Position, 1.0)).xyz)
      + (in_Weights[1] * (u_BoneTransform[ int(in_BoneID[1]) ] * vec4(in_Position, 1.0)).xyz)
      + (in_Weights[2] * (u_BoneTransform[ int(in_BoneID[2]) ] * vec4(in_Position, 1.0)).xyz)
      + (in_Weights[3] * (u_BoneTransform[ int(in_BoneID[3]) ] * vec4(in_Position, 1.0)).xyz);
```

This is what I have so far. Naturally, it will be slower than letting the shader do it, which is a shame. I'd be happy about any suggestions though.

```java
public void update() {
  // ...
  Vector3 position = marryBonesWithVector(weights, boneTransformations,currentPosition,1.0f);
  // ...
}

/**
 * Marry Bones with Vector
 *
 * @param w weights
 * @param i influences
 * @param m bone transformation matrices
 * @param t target vector (like position or normal)
 * @param f flag for position or directional vector
 */
public static void marryBonesWithVector(float[] w, int[] i, Matrix4[] m, Vector3 t, float f) {

  Vector3 influence1 = getSingleBoneInfluence(m[i[0]],t,f).mulInPlace(w[0]);
  Vector3 influence2 = getSingleBoneInfluence(m[i[1]],t,f).mulInPlace(w[1]);
  Vector3 influence3 = getSingleBoneInfluence(m[i[2]],t,f).mulInPlace(w[2]);
  Vector3 influence4 = getSingleBoneInfluence(m[i[3]],t,f).mulInPlace(w[3]);

  t.addInPlace(influence1).addInPlace(influence2).addInPlace(influence3).addInPlace(influence4);
}

/**
 * computes single bone influence
 *
 * @param m current bone transformation Matrix
 * @param t taret position vector
 * @param f flag: 1 position, 0 direction
 * @return Vector3 single bone influence
 */
private static Vector3 getSingleBoneInfluence(Matrix4 m, Vector3 t, float f) {
  float [] pI = new float[4];
  pI[0] = m.values[0]  * t.x + m.values[1]  * t.y + m.values[2]  * t.z + m.values[3]  * f;
  pI[1] = m.values[4]  * t.x + m.values[5]  * t.y + m.values[6]  * t.z + m.values[7]  * f;
  pI[2] = m.values[8]  * t.x + m.values[9]  * t.y + m.values[10] * t.z + m.values[11] * f;
  //      pI[3] = m.values[12] * t.x + m.values[13] * t.y + m.values[14] * t.z + m.values[15] * f; // not needed
  return Vector3.createNew(pI[0],pI[1],pI[2]);
}
```

Comment: Does this work, albeit slower, and you just want some validation, or is something broken (if so, what)?

Comment: the transformations look super weird, and i figured that this peace of code could be potentially a problem, since i'm not 100% sure about the mat4 * vec4(vecor3,1.0).xyz calculation (although doing the calculations on desktop with c# in shader everything works just fine :( so bascially i wanted to know if i made an error in the ladder method where i compute the bone influence for each vertex position

Comment: Ah, you should add that info to your question.  Been awhile since I've done any linear algebra / matrix stuff, so I'm not even going to guess with this - but that additional info could help others who know what's going on to troubleshoot this.

Comment: 128 bones? I think you should find a better way. That's not just a limitation of the Samsung :)

Comment: you're totally right about that but for now i just wanted to make it work, i'm not at the point of optimization just yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the shader uses a transposed matrix.

so my code works when i compute it that way:

```
/**
 * computes single bone influence
 *
 * @param m current bone transformation Matrix
 * @param t position vector
 * @param f flag: 1 position, 0 direction
 * @return Vector3 single bone influence
 */
private static Vector3 getSingleBoneInfluence(Matrix4 m, Vector3 t, float f) {
    float[] pI = new float[4];
    pI[0] = m.values[0]  * t.x + m.values[4]  * t.y + m.values[8]  * t.z + m.values[12]  * f;
    pI[1] = m.values[1]  * t.x + m.values[5]  * t.y + m.values[9]  * t.z + m.values[13]  * f;
    pI[2] = m.values[2]  * t.x + m.values[6]  * t.y + m.values[10] * t.z + m.values[14]  * f;

    return Vector3.createNew(pI[0], pI[1], pI[2]);
}
```

*edit: [understanding shader mat4 * vec4 calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745334/understanding-shader-mat4-vec4-calculation)

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer when you figure it out yourself.