# understanding shader mat4 * vec4 calculation

Tags: android, vector, matrix, shader

can someone confirm following calculation, please? :)

in normal android opengl shader the computation:

```
mat4 a;
vec3 p;

vec3 pos = (a * vec4(p,1.0)).xyz;
```

would be calculated like this:

```
pos.x = a0 * p.x + a1 * p.y + a2 * p.z + a3 * 1.0;
pos.y = a4 * p.x + a5 * p.y + a6 * p.z + a7 * 1.0;
pos.z = a8 * p.x + a9 * p.y + a10 * p.z + a11 * 1.0;
```

is this correct? or did I miss something? every help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `{{a, b, c, d},
{e, f, g, h},
{i, j, k, l},
{m, n, o, p}}
*
{w,
x,
y,
z}
=
{aw + bx + cy + dz,
ew + fx + gy + hz,
iw + jx + ky + lz,
mw + nx + oy + pz}
` so yes it's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is "yes."

This can also be factored as three dot products.

Comment: yea thanks a lot :D although i've got to add that the shader matrix is transposed for some reason or rather the matrix in my code wasn't

Answer (score 2):

Ok actually I've found a reliable source: http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf

```
vec3 v, u;
mat3 m;
```

And

```
u = m * v;
```

is equivalent to

```
u.x = m[0].x * v.x  +  m[1].x * v.y  +  m[2].x * v.z;
u.y = m[0].y * v.x  +  m[1].y * v.y  +  m[2].y * v.z;
u.z = m[0].z * v.x  +  m[1].z * v.y  +  m[2].z * v.z;
```

Therefore

```
vec3 v, u;
mat4 m;
```

And

```
u = (mat * vec4(v,1.0)).xyz
```

should be equivalent to

```
u.x = m[0].x * v.x  +  m[1].x * v.y  +  m[2].x * v.z + m[3].x * 1;
u.y = m[0].y * v.x  +  m[1].y * v.y  +  m[2].y * v.z + m[3].y * 1;
u.z = m[0].z * v.x  +  m[1].z * v.y  +  m[2].z * v.z + m[3].z * 1;
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong though.